# regex gets stuck with this call

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on a movie scraper / auto-downloader that iterates over my current movie collection, finds new recommendations, and downloads the new goods.

There is a part where I scrape IMDb for metadata and it seems to get stuck in this one spot and I can't seem to figure out why.... it has run this same code with different imdb pages just fine (this is the 29th iteration of a new page)

I am using c#!

The code:

```
    private string Match(string regex, string html, int i = 1)
    {
        return new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Multiline).Match(html).Groups[i].Value.Trim();
    }
```

regex parameter string contents:

```
 <title>.*?\\(.*?(\\d{4}).*?\\).*?</title>
```

html parameter string contents: too big to paste here, but literally the html string representation of http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4422748/combined

if in chrome, you can view easily with:

view-source:http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4422748/combined

I have paused execution in visual studio and stepped forward, it continues to run but just hangs (it doesn't let me step, it just runs). If i hit pause again it will return to the same spot with the same parameter values (and no I am not calling it in an infinite loop. I'm pretty new to Regex so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Tempted to close as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/ ... Please make sure to read first 20+ answers so you can write plausible HTML parser with regex... Or just use HtmlAgilityPack and finish all parsing  in 10 minutes :)

Comment: got a good laugh out of that "duplicate"... I was using a free parser I found on the net (which uses regex) so I was hoping I could make it work instead of rewriting everything from scratch. I will look into htmlagilitypack! thanks

Comment: what is the title it gets stuck on? and still - you should be using the HtmlAgilityPack to get to the title regardless if you're using regex to parse that further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of `.*` is like saying I want to match everything, yet nothing. Each use of it causes the parser to *backtrack* on so many different possibilities it becomes unresponsive and *appears* to lock up.

Does the person designing the pattern really not know if there is going to be text there or not for *title*? I bet 99% of the time the title has text..so why is `.*` even used, how about `.+` at least?

If you want text between the delimiters, use this

```
title\>(?<Title>[^<]+)\</title
```

Then extract the matched text through the named group "Title" instead of group[0]. Group[1] will have the actual match text as well if one *loathes* named match captures.

### Answer for Regex Haters

Use the HTML agility pack.